# Will ICAO 24 bit addresses suffer the same fate of IPv4?

Tags: faa-regulations, ads-b

As we know; both IP addresses and Mode S (ICAO) addresses are relatively short. With local networks and NAT (Network Address Translation), there is not an urgent need for transition to IPv6.

But how about Mode S addresses? With the increasing number of drones, I am assuming ADS-B Out would be mandatory in the near future for them too. Is there any discussion about the relatively short length of ICAO addresses and the problem of unique address assignment for every flying aircraft?

Comment: Do you mean "delayed introduction of CIDR"?Since it is Classless IDR. Also as far as i know, with addition of many "things" to the internet, is not NAT the only thing prolonging the life expectancy of IPv4( IPv6 has superior capabilities in nearly every aspect).

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your sentence. But in a scenario where every flying aircraft, drone or bird are forced to obtain Mode S Address(basicly joining Mode S network), what would be the answer in your opinion? Local Mode S Networks and NAT for every aircraft?

Comment: From a technical point of view ; short surveillance messages defined as 56 bit long and standard length messages  defined as 112 bit long. Both types include 24 bit address- parity fields. Increasing bit number might not be that easy, since it will need longer message definition in protocols, meaning changes in encoding and decoding methods. I would love to see what future will bring in this matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there will be an ADS-B mandate specifically for drones. Instead I expect ADS-B will be mandated for certain airspaces.

The US has taken this approach from the beginning, Australia has a combined airspace & flight rule approach (IFR in class A,B,C & E airspace). The EU so far has based the ADS-B mandate on aircraft weight (>5700 kg MTOM) or speed (>250 KTAS). That is likely to change in the future.

For drones operating outside this ADS-B mandatory airspace, no ADS-B will be necessary. I guess the number of drones inside mandatory airspace will be limited, since there is no efficient way to integrate them into the Air Traffic Control system. However, over time this will likely change.

The big problem I see is not so much the limited address space, but the overloading of the 1090MHz frequency that ADS-B will be working on. On the long term I see a need to rethink frequency allocation for surveillance and navigation (and while we are at it, communication too). The limited number of addresses should be dealt with at the same time. With so many investments in the current system, it is going to be very difficult to transition to a new system.

Comment: I remember a case which a drone operator that flew his drone near an airport was charged for endangering flight safety. This was the source of my question. Do you think a proper solution for these "incidents", as my suggestion would be dedicated-lightweight ADS-B only modules for drones(as far as i researched, there are products in this manner already. This kind of mandate would prevent unintended cases of flight safety compromise and better awareness for aircraft occasionally in same flight level with drones.

Comment: And my second question is about frequency.If I remember correctly, 1090 Mhz(also 1030 Mhz for interrogations of Mode S) was choosen to be interoperable with classic SSR Mode A/C communication. Would not frequency allocation change contradict with this concept at the first place(I am assuming you are suggesting leaving 1090 Mhz band for ADS-B)?

Comment: @MehmetÇağrıKöse - I would strongly suggest that you ask this second question as a _separate_ question, as it is rather an interesting question, and as such, should not be left buried in the comments section of an answer.